# How to use custom Viewhelpers inside a fluid template?

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x

I'm trying to use a custom view helper inside a fluid template. I followed the [official docs](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/8-Fluid/8-developing-a-custom-viewhelper.html).

I can't get it to work though. I always get the error

> The ViewHelper "blog:gravatar>" could not be resolved. Based on your spelling, the system would load the class "MyVendor\ExtKey\ViewHelpers\GravatarViewHelper", however this class does not exist.

I set the namespace in the view helper like this:
`namespace MyVendor\ExtKey\ViewHelpers;`
and include it in the fluid template like this:
`{namespace blog=MyVendor\ExtKey\ViewHelpers}`
I already tried different paths for the namespace like:

> ExtKey\Classes\ViewHelpers

thats were the view helper is located in the file structure. Or even the absolute path.

The file structure looks like this:

> extkey--Classes--ViewHelpers--GravatarViewHelper.php
>
> extkey--Resources--Private--Templates--Page--fluidtemplate.html

Is there anything i have to do beforehand, which is not written in the docs?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the vendor name "MyVendor" this name can't be freely chosen like i read somewhere in the docs.

I created the extension with the [sitepackagebuilder](https://sitepackagebuilder.com/) and the vendor name has to be whatever you entered for Company name.